# Largest Palindrome Product of 2 3 digit numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem statement:

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Here is what I've done.

```
for x in range(999,100,-1):
    for y in range(x,100,-1):
    check = str(x*y)

    check_length = len(check)

    if check_length % 2 == 0:
        if check[0:check_length//2] ==  check[check_length:check_length//2:-1]:
            print(check)
            break
```

So I've cut out all repeat products (i.e. 999x998=998x999), convert it into a string and check if the two halves are the same after reversing the second string. This produces no result whatsoever. I am not looking for an answer but a hint as to the direction and also the pointing out any problems with the code. Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
for x in range(999,100,-1):
    for y in range(x,100,-1):
    check = str(x*y)

    check_length = len(check)

    if check[0:check_length//2] ==  check[check_length:check_length//2:-1]:
        print(check)
        break
```

*Sample Output of check*

580085

906609

119911

282282

853358

**EDIT**

Here is my final version which does the trick. Thanks for all the input.

```
largest_palindrome = 0

 for x in range(999,100,-1):
     for y in range(x,100,-1):
        product = x*y
        check = str(x*y)

        if check ==  check[::-1]:
            if product > largest_palindrome:
                largest_palindrome = product

print(largest_palindrome)
```

Comment: I wouldn't check like that. I would reverse the whole thing and check.

Comment: Did you test the `check` function by feeding it a known palindrome (e.g. `12321`)? Also, ask Malik points out, how are you checking strings that don't split neatly in half (e.g. `12321`)?

Comment: Not a good fit for codereview, we only review working code, and we don't do gimme-teh-codes either, @stanpines.

Comment: It has to be greater than 100*100 since 100^2=10000 which is not a palindrome

Comment: The fact that 100*100 is wrong isn't good enough reason to ignore all the other multiples of 100.. Fortunately, in general, palindromic numbers can't be multiples of 10 (hence not of 100), since they can't have initial zeroes to match the final zeroes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check is wrong. Let’s take a look at an example:

```
>>> check = '123321'
>>> check_length = len(check)
>>> check[0:check_length//2]
'123'
>>> check[check_length:check_length//2:-1]
'12'
```

As you can see, you’re chopping off one character. That’s because you are splitting the string as `check[6:3:-1]` which keeps the index `3` out (because ranges are exclusive of the end). So correct would be the following:

```
>>> check[check_length:check_length//2 - 1:-1]
'123'
```

But you actually don’t need that complexity. There is no need to split the string in half and compare the halves. A palindrome is a string that reads forwards the same as backwards. So just compare the whole string with the whole string reversed:

```
>>> check
'123321'
>>> check[::-1]
'123321'
>>> check == check[::-1]
True
```

This also makes is easy to check one case which you didn’t account at all for: Uneven string lengths. A number `12321` is a palindrome too but because the string length is 5, you are completely ignoring it.

Finally there are two further issues with your code:

1. `break` from within the inner loop will not break the outer loop. So you will stop iterating `y` but the next iteration for `x` will start, so you are continuing the search for a while. You need a way to break the outer loop in that case too.
2. You are not looking for the *largest* palindrome. You are simply starting at the largest argument `x` and then check all possible `y` that make palindromes. But that will give you for example `998 * 583` as the largest palindrome, but there are easily numbers (with lower x) that will produce larger palindromes. So you should check all the palindromes you find, or iterate in another way.

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse(n):
    Number = n    
    Reverse = 0    
    while(Number > 0):    
        Reminder = Number %10    
        Reverse = (Reverse *10) + Reminder    
        Number = Number //10      
    return Reverse

def multiple(i, j):
    return i * j



def checkPalindrone(n, rn):
    if (n == rn):
        return True
    else:
        return False
def maxPalindrone():
    mult = 0
    returnPalidrone = []
    for i in range(100,1000):
        for j in range(100,1000):
            mult = multiple(i,j)
            if (checkPalindrone(mult, reverse(mult))):
                returnPalidrone.append(mult)
            else:
                continue
    return max(returnPalidrone)
```